# Formatting a Datetime in Angular/Ionic

Tags: angularjs, datetime, ionic-framework, date-pipe

I was wondering how I can format the text and make some part of the datetime string bold?

For example I want to make my current date time format, which looks like: 02/19/2018 16:00 CST to 02/19/2018 **16:00 CST**.

This is the code that is generating the current date time format.

`<td{{ visit['end_dte'] | date:'MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm Z'}}</td>`

I tried doing `<td{{ visit['end_dte'] | date:'MM/dd/yyyy <b>HH:mm Z</b>'}}</td>` but it made it so that the pipe was represented as text instead of bolding the time.

Comment: `<td>` make sure this isnt a simple mistake, you forgot one of the angle braceys

Comment: Thanks @Isaac but I accidentally deleted it when I was copy pasting code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Separate it into 2 different filter calls

```
<td>
  {{ visit['end_dte'] | date:'MM/dd/yyyy'}} <b>{{ visit['end_dte'] | date:'HH:mm Z'}}</b>
</td>
```